# Code for Numerical Pyramid in Java Programming

Tags: java

Create a java code that display the following figure:

```
         1
       2 3 4
     3 4 5 6 7
   4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Hey guys! New on here. We have an exercise to do involving java programming and for some reason It seems to get my head blows out in solving this problem. There's what I have done so far but the output is incorrect.

```
public class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 10;
        for (int row = 1; row <= size; row++) {
            int j = 1;
            int i = 1;
            int counter1 = 1;
            int counter2 = 1;

            // print space
            while (j++ <= size - row) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // count up
            j = size - (size - row);
            if (j == 10) j = 0;
            counter1 = 1;
            while (counter1 <= row) {
                System.out.print(j);
                if (j == 9 && counter1 != row) j = -1;
                j++;
                counter1++;
            }
            j = j - 2;
            counter2 = 1;

            // count down
            while (counter2 < row) {
                System.out.print(j--);
                if (j < 0) j = 9;
                counter2++;
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tagged `javascript`

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: As **rep-farmers** are posting different code instead of helping to fix yours and the question is duplicated I'll report it as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, pyramid of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951406/java-pyramid-of-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I can see two major mistakes in what you posted.

1. 10 is the highest number in the pyramid but it has only **4** rows. So `size` should be equal to 4 (unless it is just an example and the number of rows isn't important).
2. I don't see any reason why you make a countdown. You can see that the numbers are always increasing in the same row.

In addition to that:

- You should separate the numbers by a blank. The numbers in your example were stuck to each other. This imply that you have to change the number of spaces before each row. (In your example you can simply double the spaces)
- Really not important: you can use `System.out.println()` when you want an new line.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing counting down after the mid point of each raw. So instead of increasing number, you are decreasing in the count down part (`j` is decreasing).

And here you need 4 numbers of raws. but u have programmed for 10 numbers of raws with some conditions (here you don't need to specify the highest number. You just input the number of raws is enough. Please find the Logic below).

And even though you need to increase the number of raws, the logic should not be changed.

Logic:
For each raw the number of elements should be the raw's odd number and the 1st element of each raw should be started with the raw's number.

for example,

if we consider 3rd raw, then 3rd odd number is = `(3*2) - 1 = 5`. So number of elements in the raw is `5`.
And the start element of 3rd raw is `3`. 
So raw will be:

```
3,4,5,6,7
```

Please try below code:

```
int n = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int odd = (i*2) - 1;

        for (int j = 1; j <= odd; j++) {
            if (j==1) {

                for (int x = n; x >=i; x--)
                    System.out.print("  ");
            }

            System.out.print(((j + i)-1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output is:

```
      1 
    2 3 4 
  3 4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: The question is obviously homework so it's better to point the mistakes than to give a full solution. Not only that but you don't fix the code of the question but you give a new one. What will the asker learn this way?

Comment: @user270349 I'll add the reason shortly

Comment: I removed the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

class Pyramid {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myLevel;
    int i, j, k;
    int x = 1;
    myLevel = 6;

    for (i = 1; i <= myLevel; i++) {

        for (k = 1; k <= myLevel - i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (j = k + 1; j <= myLevel; j++) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        for (int l = myLevel; l > k - 1; l--) {
            System.out.print(x);
        }
        x++;
        System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

}